# How to compare averages of averages? Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean

Problem at hand: I have 2 pairs of equal time frames (say days) trying to compare if a change on a website caused the average time to change significantly or not. I know that this could be a classic example of paired t-test (given it follows all assumptions), but my question is can we really work on the average of already an averaged metric? Are there any cons of this?

Below is a dummy data

Before Change:

```
Average Time On Site:
0:01:30
0:03:13
0:01:08
0:01:47
0:01:40
0:01:46
0:03:44
0:02:35
0:01:53
0:01:42
0:01:19
0:02:13
0:01:52
0:01:42
0:02:29
0:03:43
0:02:30
0:03:24
0:02:41
0:01:07
```

After Change:

```
Average Time On Site:
0:01:49
0:03:10
0:02:34
0:02:15
0:01:15
0:01:24
0:01:43
0:02:12
0:01:26
0:01:00
0:01:34
0:03:40
0:02:33
0:01:43
0:02:25
0:01:42
0:01:04
0:02:31
0:01:18
0:03:04
```

Comment: It's actually good in some ways that each row of data is an averaged time. By the CLT, this random variable is normally distributed (assuming that the sample sizes used to create each average are reasonably big). This means that the difference between the before and after average time on site will also be normally distributed. However, two additional critical assumptions for this difference are: they are drawn from a normal distribution with the 1) same mean and 2) variance. If you think your data satisfies this then go ahead and use the paired t-test.

Comment: An example where the equal variance assumption might be violated is if the change in average time on site is proportional to the old time spent on site.